# How to change the icon shown in "running apps" screen in my app?

Tags: android, icons

I have changed my launcher icon but when i am in the "running apps" screen is shows the android icon as shown in the image below :

[image: screenshot]

Does anyone know how can i fix this ?

This is the  manifest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="stelios.concerts">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Swipe_activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"

            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: add your manifest file too

Comment: You haven't changed your icon here android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"  It is set to ic_launcher

Answer (score 3):

1. Set the icon.

> ```
> android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
> android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
> ```

2. If it doesn't work, try to reboot your phone.

Answer (score 0):

That icon is defined into the manifest. When you create a new project in Android Studio, a default one is created (exactly the one you refer to) and it has ic_launcher as name.
To change the icon you should first upload a new icon (a `.png` file) into the mipmap folder of your project and the change the name of the default icon delcared int the manifest with your icon's name.

E.g.
`android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` to `android:icon="@mipmap/your_icon_name"`